# Quando devo criar uma classe?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu sei que parece uma pergunta bem boba, mas eu estou iniciando agora no mundo da programação (focada em mobile).

Quando eu crio um app ele fica com todas as funções dentro das Activities, aí eu nunca sei quando eu devo tirar métodos e atributos da classe e separar-las.
ah! isso também serve pra organização dos pacotes e das classes

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Para combinar com o avatar, só faltou fazer a pergunta assim: ["qua-qua-quando devo criar uma cla-cla-cla-claaaaaaaaaasse!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYdpOjletnc)  :P

Comment: UAHUEUAHUEH, boa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende,

Cada actividade tem um ciclo de vida próprio, que pode ou não afetar o ciclo de vida da própria app.

Recomendo a ler [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

E depois tem fragmentos, que ajuda a app a ser dividida por blocos da própria app, que pode depois reutilizar em diversas actividades.
Recomendo a ler [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

E depois, seguindo os padrões de Java, deve programar seguindo o paradigma POO, criando classes para representar diversas coisas (objectos ou coisas abstractas)

Comment: Ow, muito obrigado. Aliás, alguma dica pra quem tá iniciando agora?

Comment: Recomendo ler certos Android Cookbook's e ver tutoriais de coisas básicas em android, como iniciar actividades, etc.

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do conceito de que uma `classe` é uma estrutura que abstrai um conjunto de objetos com características similares ela pode conter métodos ou atributos. Sendo assim você poderá ter uma classe para representar uma entidade do seu banco por exemplo ou uma classe que contenha métodos para realizar operações no seu banco. Antes de começar a codificar sugiro dar uma boa lida em um material sobre `POO`
[Conceitos de Orientação a Objetos - Ufpa](http://www.ufpa.br/cdesouza/teaching/es/3-OO-concepts.pdf)
[Programação Orientada a Objetos - Unicamp](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/PooJava/Aulas/poojava.pdf)